# How to make this code non-case sensitive?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and so I'm trying out some stuff to see if I actually understood. I was able to make this "program" non-case sensitive, but really poorly (since I had to make 3 variables for the same answer, just to make it non-case sensitive). How can I make this code better?

```
fav_color = "Red"
fav_color2 = "RED"
fav_color3 = "red"
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    x = input("What's Carlos' favorite color? ")
    guess_count += 1

    if x == fav_color:
        print("You win!")
        break
    if x == fav_color2:
        print("You win!")
        break
    if x == fav_color3:
        print("You win!")
        break
```

Comment: `'Red'` or `'RED'` in lowercase will be `'red'`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Convert the string returned from input to lowercase with the `.lower()` string method.**

That is to say,

```
fav_color = 'red'
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input('What's Carlos' favorite color? ').lower()
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == fav_color:
        print("You win!")
        break
```

---

Just to give you a feel for how the `.lower()` method works, I'll provide some examples:

```
>>> 'Hello'.lower()
'hello'
>>> 'hello'.lower()
'hello'
>>> 'HELLO'.lower()
'hello'
>>> 'HeLLo HOW aRe YOu ToDAY?'.lower()
'hello how are you today?'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `str.lower()` (or `upper()`)

```
fav_color = "Red"

guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while guess_count < guess_limit:
    x = input("What's Carlos' favorite color? ")
    guess_count += 1

    if x.lower() == fav_color.lower():
        print("You win!")
        break
```